# Vertical alignment of text inside div

Tags: html, css

I really need help on this: cracking me for 2nd day already. I have the following code:

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font: 16px Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
color: #444;
line-height: 1.5rem;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
text-decoration: none;
}

.inlbtn {
width: 2rem;
height: 2rem;
display: table;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
color: #666;
border: 1px solid #939393;
}

.plus {
font-size: 1.5rem;
font-weight: bold;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
}

.plus:before {
content: "+";
}

<div class='inlbtn'><span class='plus'></span></div>
```

It basically has a div and span inside with a "+" symbol. The horizontal alignment seems fine, but the vertical is a little shifted down. How to make it perfectly centered vertically?

I played around with the code and it seems the code under * is the culprit, but why?

Here's fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jk34josq/2/

Comment: Can u create a fiddle?

Comment: Is there a reason why you have a div and a span? And why use the `:before` pseudo class, and not just add it as a text to the element??

Comment: Here's a Fiddle of it... simple copy/ paste. http://jsfiddle.net/jk34josq/1/

Comment: @AkhilNamboothiri, edited, thanks to LinkinTED :)

Comment: @LinkinTED, it's actually how i did it in my code, but since i couldn't fix it, i started to play around with the span: the behaviour is the same anyway...

Comment: @DimaDz, that's exactly my point, if the behaviour is the same, then why use extra elements and content? :)

Comment: @LinkinTED, although one potential problem is if you use display: table on the .inlbtn and display: table-cell with :before (which is better than flexbox in terms of browser compatibility), you can't set a negative margin with :before. :)

Comment: Let me put up an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do everything right, I always use the same method. The problem is that this line

```
content: "+";
```

is a piece of text, so it automatically has top margin inside of the `line-height` preserved for the capital letters (and + symbol is not the one); the margin value could also be different depending on the font.

As a proof try the following:

```
content: "A";
```

This looks centered.

What you can do to avoid this behavior:

1. Negative margin / top property
2. Use image instead of text
3. Maybe play with reducing the `line-height` property but I have doubts about this method

Comment: thanks, man. i played with the line-height already. no result. i guess my problem comes from the html's centering relatively the height of capital letters.

Comment: @DimaDz it does, it treats the text inside of your element as one more block with the height of the text, it is fixed to the capital letters, that's why you have this problem.

Comment: @DimaDz it probably won't as I explicitly wrote it. Try the other two methods, they should work

Answer (score 1):

I would use only a single HTML element, since there is no need for using an extra element nor a `:before` pseudo class:

```
<div class='inlbtn'>+</div>
```

Then I would use `display: inline-block`, instead of table.

As mentioned by Simon in his answer, the `+` character is smaller than `A`. But instead of using negative margins or paddings, I would alter the line-height:

```
.inlbtn {
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #666;
    border: 1px solid #939393;
}
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jk34josq/13/)

Comment: yeah, man, that's a good option. only problem, i think, is to better use pseudo classes because i have other buttons with other symbols. then i have to change the line-height manually for each symbol of the button. i'll upvote your answer once i have a sufficient repu. simon was a little quicker than you, that's why i didn't give the credit to you. :)

Comment: No problem :). It doesnt matter if you use this or a pseudo class, either way will youll need to manually adjust the line height or padding for each separate symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zwc6Lu8m/)**

```
.inlbtn {
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #666;
    border: 1px solid #939393;
}
.plus {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
}
.plus:before {
    content:"+";
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This method doesn't work - try to use "." instead of "+", to see that.